# Using the ROLLUP total within a query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle9i

Table Costs:

```
Item | Cost
 Car |  10
 Cat |   2
 Dog |   3
 Fish|   1
```

Is it possible to use the sum within a per-row query?

```
SELECT Item, Cost, Cost/sum(cost) "Percent" from Costs where ...
```

to get:

```
Item | Cost | Percent
 Car |  10  | 0.625
 Cat |   2  | 0.125
 Dog |   3  | 0.1875
 Fish|   1  | 0.0625
```

This is just a simple example. My query is a lot more complicated, so I'd rather not do another full table scan to get a "select sum(cost) where ...". Would it possible to do this using grouping/rollup?

Comment: let's say your cost table has a million of rows, and your complicated query filters out only 10 rows for result set. do you need a sum of your 10 rows or of the whole million?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [RATIO_TO_REPORT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96540/functions96a.htm#85802) function to get the ratio, without calculating the sum.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f779a/1)

**Query 1**:

```
select item,
       cost,
       ratio_to_report(cost) over () as percent
from costs
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f779a/1/0)**:

```
| ITEM | COST | PERCENT |
|------|------|---------|
|  car |   10 |   0.625 |
|  cat |    2 |   0.125 |
|  dog |    3 |  0.1875 |
| fish |    1 |  0.0625 |
```